# Accuracy issue with TF.Learn DNNClassifier and LinearClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tensorflow

I coded a little piece of code to find the best classifiers to fit a CDC dataset. First I tried the various scikit-learn classifiers then I decided to add the TF.Learn ones (DNNClassifier and LinearClassifier) as the API is nearly the same.

Then when I compare the results, all scikit-learn models easily reach a 60-70% accuracy and with TF.learn DNNClassifiers and LinearClassifier I cannot do more than 38% and takes a lot of time (or even hangs if I don't set the number of steps while fitting the model).

I probably made a mistake but I don't see it...

Here is the code extract:

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2)    

for classifier in classifiers:
    if classifier == "TF Deep Neural Network":
        feature_columns = learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(X_train)   
        clf = DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns, 
                           hidden_units=[10,10,10], 
                           n_classes=2, enable_centered_bias=None);
        clf.fit(X_train, Y_train, steps=200)
    elif classifier == "TF Linear Classifier":
        feature_columns = learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(X_train)   
        clf = LinearClassifier(n_classes=2, feature_columns=feature_columns)     
        clf.fit(X_train, Y_train, steps=200)
    else:
        clf = getInstance(classifiers[classifier][0], classifiers[classifier][1], classifiers[classifier][2])
        clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)


    # predict on test data
    prediction = clf.predict(X_test)

    # compute accuracy and sum it to the previous ones
    accuracy = accuracy_score(Y_test, prediction)
```

Results extract:

```
classifier Gaussian Naive Bayes accuracy 0.85
classifier K-Nearest Neighbors accuracy 0.87
classifier TF Deep Neural Network accuracy 0.4
classifier Random Forest accuracy 0.85
classifier TF Linear Classifier accuracy 0.4
classifier Decision Tree accuracy 0.87
classifier Neural Network accuracy 0.4
classifier AdaBoost accuracy 0.86
classifier Linear Support Vector Machine accuracy 0.88
classifier Radial Basic Function Support Vector Machine accuracy 0.74
```

Full code here: https://github.com/shazz/gender_classification_challenge/blob/master/demo_with_BRFSS_and_TF.py

So, any insights on why the accuracy is so low (and takes a lot of time to fit) with TF.Learn will be appreciated !

**UPDATE based on Kumara's answer**

I modified the labels to be 0 or 1 (and not 1 and 2 as in the original CDC dataset) and I ran the classifiers tests again. The new results are :

```
classifier AdaBoost accuracy 0.87 
classifier Linear Support Vector Machine accuracy 0.86
classifier K-Nearest Neighbors accuracy 0.86
classifier Gaussian Naive Bayes accuracy 0.85 
classifier Random Forest accuracy 0.85
classifier Radial Basic Function Support Vector Machine accuracy 0.83
classifier Decision Tree accuracy 0.83
classifier Neural Network accuracy 0.64 
classifier TF Deep Neural Network accuracy 0.63 
classifier TF Linear Classifier accuracy 0.62
```

So still fairly behind the scikit learn classifiers.
What may make sense is that the DNNClassifier is as "bad" as the scikit learn Multi-layer Perceptron classifier.

Do you think that considering the kind of data and the classifiers, that's normal that the TF.Learn DNNClassifier and LinearClassifier don't have a good accuracy ?

Comment: Can you try for longer time (more steps) and see if the results are consistent? 200 steps seems awfully little.

Comment: I just tried with 5000 steps, same result, around 34% accuracy (but now takes 5s to compute compared to instant results from scikit learn classifiers)

Comment: Just curious, what does tf.learn's RandomForestEstimator give you? It has slightly different usage than e.g. the DNNClassifier, look at examples/random_forest_mnist.py for an example.

Comment: @jonas25007: I took a look at the example, but I did not understand how to use the RFE in this example. I'll give another look.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the TF.learn classifiers are expecting class labels as indices (i.e. y must be 0 or 1 for a 2 class problem), while the scikit learn classifiers treat y as arbitrary values (e.g. 77 and 99 are valid values for y in a 2 class problem).

In this case, looking at the data, the class labels are 1 and 2.  As a result, the TF.learn training is seeing an out-of-bounds value of 2 occasionally, which it ignores.  And as a result it always predicts '1' (this becomes obvious if you print 'prediction' and 'Y_test' after calling predict()).  The label value '1' is probably 40% of the data, and hence it results in 40% accuracy.

The fix is to map the labels to class indices (e.g. label '1' to index 0 and label '2' to index 1).  For example, I did this with "Y = Y - 1" after loading the data (though a more general solution would be better for arbitrary values):

```
# load data and convert Y into 1d vector
X, Y = data_importer.load_data(500)
print("X", X.shape, "Y", Y.shape)

# FIX: Y/Labels are "1" and "2" for male/female.  We should convert
# these to indices into a 2 class space
# (i.e. "1" is index 0, and "2" is index 1).
Y = Y - 1

# train and check the model against the test data for each classifier
iterations = 1
results = {}
for itr in range(iterations):

    # Resuffle training/testing datasets by sampling randomly 80/20% of the input data
    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2)
    ...
```

Ideally the two APIs would be compatible, or at least the TF.learn API should more clearly document this distinction.  Though arguably using class indices is more efficient and cleaner for arbitrary classes (e.g. image classes).

Comment: Thanks Kumara... Looks dumb now :) But was not easy to spot. So I modified the labels to be 0 or 1 (man/woman) and I ran again the classifiers tests. Thatś better but not yet that good. I updated the main question.